# Creating unique variable names in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have a script which can be used multiple times per script, each instance of the script requires some php stuff to be done, I need to create a unique name for each instance variable e.g.

I need:

```
$typedbefore1 = get_post_meta( $text, '_cmb2_typed_text', true );
$typed1 = '"' . implode('","', $typedbefore1) . '"';

$typedbefore2 = get_post_meta( $text, '_cmb2_typed_text', true );
$typed2 = '"' . implode('","', $typedbefore2) . '"';

$typedbefore3 = get_post_meta( $text, '_cmb2_typed_text', true );
$typed3 = '"' . implode('","', $typedbefore3) . '"';
```

The variable $text is a number generated by the user so I can use that e.g.

```
$typedbefore.$text = get_post_meta( $text, '_cmb2_typed_text', true );
$typed.$text = '"' . implode('","', $typedbefore.$text) . '"';
```

That doesn't work (obviously), is there a way to do what I need?

Converted to arrays but my implode isn't working:

```
$typedbefore = array();
$typedbefore[$text] = get_post_meta( $text, '_cmb2_typed_text', true );
$typed = array();
$typed[$text] = '"' . implode('","', $typedbefore[$text]) . '"';
```

It's still storing the $typed as an array, how can I do the second part so it implodes the data from $typedbefore?

Comment: Why not make array for the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really *should* use arrays, as *MightyPork* suggested...:

```
$typedbefore = array();
$typedbefore[$text] = "value";
```

**UPDATE:** To answer OP last question: from [here](http://it.wpseek.com/function/get_post_meta/) I see wordpress finction `get_post_meta()` returns `array` only if it's last parameter is `false`. But I see you use `true`, so it should return a single value. So you shouldn't use implode (which expects an array as 2nd parameter) with a single value.
I don't really understand what's your definitive goal, so I can't give a more specific comment, sorry...

Comment: Added more to my question, it has helped with the text part but I can't get the data from $typedbefore to be imploded, as it's caught in 2 arrays

Comment: Basically the post meta is an array of text strings which I am then printing into a peice of javascript which needs to be comma'd hence the implode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable variables like:

```
$varname = "typedbefore".$text;
echo $$varname;
```

This is the same, if you say:

```
echo $typedbefore1 //If $text == 1
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

But much more better, if your are collecting your  data into an array, and use that.